# Как распарсить JSON в таблицу с 3 колонками при помощи MS SQL?

Tags: python, json, sql-server, парсер

Есть json следующей стуктуры:

```
{
    "target": "A",
    "datapoints": [
      [ 1404.5, 1547596800 ],
      [ 1536.5, 1547683200 ],
      [ 1683.6666666666667, 1548115200 ],
      [ 1789.75, 1548201600 ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "B",
    "datapoints": [
      [ 1518.0, 1547596800 ],
      [ 1547.5, 1547683200 ],
      [ 1580.6666666666667, 1548115200 ],
      [ 1593.0, 1548201600 ]
    ]
  }
```

Как мне распарсить это в таблицу с тремя колонками при помощи SQL? Если с SQL  невозможно сделать, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это на Python?
Примерно так должно быть:

```
Target|Value|Time
A|1404.5|1547596800
A|1536.5|1547683200
...........
B|1593.0|1548201600
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На Python, с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import json
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

with open(json_file_name) as f:
    d = json.load(f)

res = (pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, "datapoints", meta=["target"])
         .rename(columns={0:"Value", 1:"Time"}))
```

результат:

```
In [42]: res
Out[42]:
         Value        Time target
0  1404.500000  1547596800      A
1  1536.500000  1547683200      A
2  1683.666667  1548115200      A
3  1789.750000  1548201600      A
4  1518.000000  1547596800      B
5  1547.500000  1547683200      B
6  1580.666667  1548115200      B
7  1593.000000  1548201600      B
```

PS при помощи метода [`df.to_sql("sql_tab_name", sqlalchemy_engine, ...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) можно сохранить Pandas DataFrame в таблицу БД.